# Yocto - clean up sources every time you build an image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am using a Linux build with Yocto on which my application is running. A few times it happened that after rebuilding the image I had an old version of my application. Now before every image build I call in the console
`bitbake my_recipe -c cleanall`. Is there any way to force what `cleanall` does in the `.bb` file with the recipe for my application?

**EDIT:**
This is my recipe. When I test my new branch I use `SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"`, when I prepare some stable version, I set a proper commit hash to the variable `SRCREV`.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Description"
LICENSE="CLOSED"

DEPENDS += "util-linux openssl"

#SRCREV = "last_commit_hash"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
SRC_URI = "git://path_to_github_repo;protocol=ssh;branch=my_test_branch\
          \     
          "
inherit cmake
```

Comment: Can you post the source code of your recipe? If your source code is changing, you need to ensure that the `PV` (package version) is changing too. If your recipe code is changing, you need to bump `PR` (recipe revision). See: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html#incrementing-a-package-version

Comment: I've edited my question. Probably you're wright. I never change my PV. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbake will only rebuild the package if the `PV` (package version) or `PR` (recipe revision) changes.

In your recipe, the `SRCREV` is changing automatically due to the use of `AUTOREV`, however it is not included in `PV`, and so the recipe does not get rebuilt because the cache already contains a build for that `PV`.

You need to include `SRCPV` (source version) in `PV`, for example:

```py
PV = "1.0+git${SRCPV}"
```

For more detail on this, refer to "[Automatically Incrementing a Package Version Number](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html#automatically-incrementing-a-package-version-number)" in the docs.